# Return flow collect in let kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am trying to call 3 api's one after the other once the response is received.

These api's are called on the basis of checking some repository data is null or not

```
suspend fun getCode(): Flow<Result<ActivationCode?>>{
    repository.settings?.let {settings->
        if (!settings.urlScheme.isNullOrEmpty() && !settings.softwareStatement.isNullOrEmpty() && !settings.requestorID.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            apiFirst(
                settings.urlScheme!!,
                settings.requestorID!!,
                settings.softwareStatement!!
            ).collect { result ->
                result.onSuccess { apiFirstResponse ->
                    apiFirstResponse?.let { registrationInfo ->
                        apiSecond(
                            url = settings.urlScheme!!,
                            clientId = registrationInfo.clientId,
                            clientSecret = registrationInfo.clientSecret,
                            grantType = registrationInfo.grantTypes[0]
                        ).collect { result ->
                            result.onSuccess { tokenResponse ->
                                tokenResponse?.let { tokenDetails ->
                                    return@let apiThird(
                                        settings.urlScheme!!,
                                        settings.requestorID!!,
                                        tokenDetails.type.plus(" ").plus(tokenDetails.token)
                                    ).collect()
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        
    }
}return emptyFlow()}
```

Although I don't get any error but always empty flow is returned.

The function should return response of my 3rd API.

Comment: Why would it not return an empty flow, if you returned it explicitly: `return emptyFlow()`?

Comment: did you try using a debugger to see what your code actually does?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `return@let` means. You're not returning from `getCode()` at that point, just from the lambda you passed to `let`. Basically overall `getCode()` does this: 1) call `apiFirst`, 2) on each call's future result, install a callback that will call `apiSecond` and do some stuff, 3) return empty flow

Comment: `return emptyFlow()` is the only line of code here that returns anything from this function. Judging from the unnecessary `suspend` keyword and nested flow collection, it seems you have some misconceptions about how flows work and what they're for. It's hard to tell what the intended behavior of this function is. You are making a series of API calls, but why are they returning flows of results instead of just a single result?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty confusing. You use flows everywhere, even in places that seem like single-result api calls. For this answer I assume all functions: `getCode()` `apiFirst()`, `apiSecond()` and `apiThird()` return flows that are expected to always emit only once - with either success or failure.

If this is the case then again: the main problem in your code is overusing flows and results. They are powerful tools, but they are more complicated, harder to use and may be confusing for a simple case like just fetching a result. Such case can be represented by a function which simply returns a value directly. If the operation is asynchronous, we can use a suspend function.

If you would use suspend functions and no flows or `Result` objects, your code would be as simple as:

```kotlin
suspend fun getCode(): ActivationCode? {
    val registrationInfo = apiFirst(...)
    val tokenDetails = apiSecond(...)
    return apiThird(...)
}
```

And it would even properly handle errors, which your current code ignores!

Of course, using `Result` vs exceptions is a matter of taste. If you keep using results, you will need some additional code for handling successes and failures, but it won't be as bad as when using flows.

If you can't convert existing functions to use suspend instead of flows and if it is true they always emit only once, then you can solve your problem by using `first()`:

```kotlin
suspend fun getCode(): ActivationCode? {
    val registrationInfo = apiFirst(...).first().getOrThrow()
    val tokenDetails = apiSecond(...).first().getOrThrow()
    return apiThird(...).first().getOrThrow()
}
```

Again, you may like to handle errors through result objects - then you need additional code.